# How do I return rows with a specific value first and order by a different column?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I need to write a query that will pull a record with a certain ID first then order the rest of the list by a different column

This is what I have done so far but it is not ordering it by score, only ID with the id I need at top

```
  SELECT *
  FROM answer
  WHERE parentid = '{$question_id}'
  ORDER BY CASE id WHEN '{$answerid}' THEN 1 ELSE score END DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM answer
  WHERE parentid = '{$question_id}'
  ORDER BY CASE id WHEN '{$answerid}' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC, score DESC
```